# Customization of managed package visualforce pages?

Tags: managed-package, dynamic-visualforce, customization

Does anyone know of any way to provide a managed visualforce page inside a managed package that customers can override with their own visualforce page layout and/or controller logic? Any concrete solution for this ?

Comment: Is this part of your own managed package or or a customization of someone else's managed package?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the solution by setting everything to `global`, there could also be a configuration only route by using custom settings and fieldsets.

- fieldsets could be used to configure the fields, which should be displayed
- custom settings could be used to provide default values or required/read only status for each field from the fieldset

This would benefit customers, which do not have the expertise creating a new VF page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If

- the controller is `global`
- all its public properties are `global`
- all its public methods are `global`

the developer in the local org can copy/paste your packaged VisualForce to create their own, and reference your controller, and all its properties and methods. They will need to add the namespace references to class name and object/field names.

If you want them to be able to extend your managed package class and override its methods, then

- the controller should be defined `global virtual`
- all its public methods should be defined `global virtual`

Comment: Also, depending on the customization (i.e. headers, footers, stuff around it but not inside it) you could look into a component that the clients can use on their page. All depends on what you mean by customization